# Javascript loop scope and buttons

Tags: javascript, loops, button, dynamic, scope

So I would like to have a button dynamically created based on the element of an array but I run into errors when trying to pass arguments to the onclick function

```
function bringforward(maincourse){
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.id="Current class" 
  newdiv.style="background-color:#207420;height:440px;width:440px";

for(var i = 0;i<maincourse.gradingareas.length; i++){

 var gradeplace = document.createElement('p');
 gradeplace.id = grades;
 newdiv.appendChild(gradeplace);

 var button = document.createElement('button');
 button.innerHTML = 'Add Grade';
 button.onclick = function myfunc(){AddGrade(maincourse.gradingareas[i])};
 gradeplace.appendChild(button);
}
```

The AddGrade function is a simple alert that will push the value given

```
function AddGrade(toadd){
var newgrade=prompt("Please enter a grade scaled up to 100 points","0 - 100");
if (newgrade!=null){
  toadd.grades.push(newgrade);
  }
}
```

The course and grading area "objects":

```
function Course(name, gradingareas, finalgrade) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gradingareas = gradingareas;  //array of gradingareas
    this.finalgrade = finalgrade;
}
function GradingArea(name, weight, grades){
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.grades = grades;  //array of grades
}
```

I thought that wrapping the function in onClick would take care of the scope problem but I get an error in Addgrade saying it is trying to access a field of an undefined variable.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Question is asked in many forms on stackoverflow, problem is the `i` is a reference, so when you click it will be equal to `maincourse.gradingareas.length`

Comment: Is there a way to dereference because I use it in the same loop for `maincourse.gradingareas[i].name` so why does it not work the same way?